# I need to create a conditional formula in Excel with multiple conditions including relative and non-relative conditions

Tags: excel

[image]

I have columns of criticality ratings in Columns AD through AI – each column has either a 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, N/A, or is blank.  Column AJ is simply a placeholder column and Column AK is where I do my calculations to come up with a rebalanced criticality rating by multiplying each of the ratings from the first six columns by the weight of that rating area – in my instance, those weights are 30%, 20%, 20%, 10%, 15%, 5% across the six columns and these weights are listed in Row 729.  I have two goals in processing the 727 rows of data:

1. If there is an ‘N/A’ or a blank in a column(s), take the percentages from those columns and reassign them ***equally*** to the other columns.  So, in the first row in the image, the ratings are 5, BLANK, 2, 1, 1, 5 and the weights are 30%, 20%, 20%, 10%, 15%, 5%.  If there was no reassignment, the formula would be (5 * 30%) + (BLANK * 20%) +(2 * 20%) + (1 * 10%) + (1 * 15%) + (5 * 5%) = 1.5 + 0 + .4 + .1 + .15 + .25 = 2.4, which is the placeholder AJ column.  My formula determines that the N/A and blank add up to columns representing 20% and there are 5 columns that have values in them, so I add 4% to each of those 5 columns, and my new math becomes (5 * 34%) + (BLANK * 24%) +(2 * 24%) + (1 * 14%) + (1 * 19%) + (5 * 9%) = 1.7 + 0 + .48 + .14 + .19 + .45 = 2.96, which is the rebalanced AK column.  Everything works great and the formula I use in Excel is:

=LET(total,SUMIF(AD2:AI2,"N/A",$AD$729:$AI$729)+SUMIF(AD2:AI2,"",$AD$729:$AI$729),count,COUNTIFS(AD2:AI2,">=1",AD2:AI2,"<=5"),SUM(IFERROR((AD$729:AI$729+total/count)*AD2:AI2,0)))

My question is regarding the next goal:

2. If there is an ‘N/A’ or a blank in a column(s), take the percentages from those columns and reassign them ***based on their original weights*** to the other columns.  So, in the first row in the image, the ratings are 5, BLANK, 2, 1, 1, 5 and the weights are 30%, 20%, 20%, 10%, 15%, 5%.  How do I write the formula so that in this instance the 20% representing the BLANK in Column AF is added to AD and AF through AI based on the percentages of the columns in AD and AF through AI?  I would still need to know ‘total’, which is the percentage to reassign, and in this case is 20%.  But how do I look at the remaining columns, which in this case would be 30%, 20%, 10%, 15%, 5%, and reassign the 20% such that the ***new percentages would be the same relative to each other?***  Column AD starts out at 30%,  Column AG starts out at 10%, and Column AH starts out at 15%, so AD needs to wind up with a weight three times as much as AG and twice as much as AH, and I need to account for the fact that any number of columns (up to all 6) can have blanks or N/A’s.  In this instance the new weighted percentages would be 37.5%, 0%, 25%, 12.5%, 18.75%, 6.25%.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would have a cell that is added to each of the cells needing the "top up" and base the calculation on the iferror() I gave you before.

Comment: Yes, starting off with 50 or 60 IF clauses quite a ride to solve OP’s assignment for him.

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike - you're always very helpful and it's appreciated - not sure what you mean or how that would be implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following crazy formula?

```
=IF(OR(AD2="N/A",AD2=0),0,AD2*AD$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AE2="N/A",AE2=0),0,AE2*AE$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AF2="N/A",AF2=0),0,AF2*AF$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AG2="N/A",AG2=0),0,AG2*AG$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AH2="N/A",AH2=0),0,AH2*AH$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AI2="N/A",AI2=0),0,AI2*AI$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))
```

This one is tuned for the row 2. Weight are assumed to be stored as percentage (therefore if the cell format is set as general, 30% will be shown as 0,3).

#### The building up

First it return the base weight for the given cell if it's appropriate:

<sup>**weight** * AND(**value**<>0, **value**<>"N/A")</sup>

```
AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")
```

---

which is repeated for each cell of the row:

<sup>**previous formula for cell 1** + **previous formula for cell 2** + **previous formula for cell 3** + **previous formula for cell 4** + **previous formula for cell 5** + **previous formula for cell 6**</sup>

```
(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A"))
```

---

which is used to divide the product of value and weight:

<sup>**value** * **weight** / **previous formula**</sup>

```
AD2*AD$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A"))
```

---

which is actually calulated only if necessary:

<sup>IF(OR(**value** = "N/A", **value** = 0), 0, **previous formula**)</sup>

```
IF(OR(AD2="N/A",AD2=0),0,AD2*AD$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))
```

---

which is repeated for each cell of the row:

<sup>**previous formula for cell 1** + **previous formula for cell 2** + **previous formula for cell 3** + **previous formula for cell 4** + **previous formula for cell 5** + **previous formula for cell 6**</sup>

```
=IF(OR(AD2="N/A",AD2=0),0,AD2*AD$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AE2="N/A",AE2=0),0,AE2*AE$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AF2="N/A",AF2=0),0,AF2*AF$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AG2="N/A",AG2=0),0,AG2*AG$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AH2="N/A",AH2=0),0,AH2*AH$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AI2="N/A",AI2=0),0,AI2*AI$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))
```

### EDIT: comment's request

We need to dynamically change the reference to the (appropriate cell in the) row 729. To achieve this, we will use this formula:

<sup>INDIRECT( **hardcoded column** & ROW( **top-left cell of the vehicle list** ) - 1 + MATCH( **cell with the kind of the given vehicle** , **vehicle list** , 0 ))</sup>

```
INDIRECT("AD"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))
```

---

which we will adapt for each cell needed:

| Previous reference | New formula |
| --- | --- |
| AD$729 | INDIRECT("AD"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0)) |
| AE$729 | INDIRECT("AE"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0)) |
| AF$729 | INDIRECT("AF"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0)) |
| AG$729 | INDIRECT("AG"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0)) |
| AH$729 | INDIRECT("AH"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0)) |
| AI$729 | INDIRECT("AI"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0)) |

---

so we will be able to substitute them accordingly and obtain this:

```
=IF(OR(AD2="N/A",AD2=0),0,AD2*INDIRECT("AD"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))/(INDIRECT("AD"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AE"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AF"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AG"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AH"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AI"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AE2="N/A",AE2=0),0,AE2*INDIRECT("AE"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))/(INDIRECT("AD"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AE"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AF"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AG"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AH"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AI"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AF2="N/A",AF2=0),0,AF2*INDIRECT("AF"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))/(INDIRECT("AD"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AE"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AF"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AG"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AH"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AI"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AG2="N/A",AG2=0),0,AG2*INDIRECT("AG"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))/(INDIRECT("AD"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AE"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AF"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AG"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AH"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AI"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AH2="N/A",AH2=0),0,AH2*INDIRECT("AH"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))/(INDIRECT("AD"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AE"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AF"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AG"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AH"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AI"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AI2="N/A",AI2=0),0,AI2*INDIRECT("AI"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))/(INDIRECT("AD"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AE"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AF"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AG"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AH"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AI"&ROW($AD$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$B$729:$B$734,0))*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))
```

#### Second edit

I've re-written the formula tuning it for the new request. Try it:

```
=IF(OR(AL2="N/A",AL2=0),0,AL2*INDIRECT("AL"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))/(INDIRECT("AL"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AL2<>0,AL2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AM"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AM2<>0,AM2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AN"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AN2<>0,AN2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AO"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AO2<>0,AO2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AP"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AP2<>0,AP2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AM2="N/A",AM2=0),0,AM2*INDIRECT("AM"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))/(INDIRECT("AL"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AL2<>0,AL2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AM"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AM2<>0,AM2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AN"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AN2<>0,AN2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AO"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AO2<>0,AO2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AP"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AP2<>0,AP2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AN2="N/A",AN2=0),0,AN2*INDIRECT("AN"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))/(INDIRECT("AL"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AL2<>0,AL2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AM"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AM2<>0,AM2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AN"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AN2<>0,AN2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AO"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AO2<>0,AO2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AP"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AP2<>0,AP2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AO2="N/A",AO2=0),0,AO2*INDIRECT("AO"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))/(INDIRECT("AL"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AL2<>0,AL2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AM"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AM2<>0,AM2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AN"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AN2<>0,AN2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AO"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AO2<>0,AO2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AP"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AP2<>0,AP2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AP2="N/A",AP2=0),0,AP2*INDIRECT("AP"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))/(INDIRECT("AL"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AL2<>0,AL2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AM"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AM2<>0,AM2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AN"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AN2<>0,AN2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AO"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AO2<>0,AO2<>"N/A")+INDIRECT("AP"&ROW(AL$729)-1+MATCH(B2,$AK$729:$AK$734,0))*AND(AP2<>0,AP2<>"N/A")))
```

Here a table to make the range change easier:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | weight sheet | Sheet1 |  |  |  |  |
|  | weight row | 729 |  |  |  |  |
|  | weight column | AL | =LEFT(MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(C3&"1"),0,1)),2,99),FIND("$",MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(C3&"1"),0,1)),2,99))-1) | =LEFT(MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(D3&"1"),0,1)),2,99),FIND("$",MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(D3&"1"),0,1)),2,99))-1) | =LEFT(MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(E3&"1"),0,1)),2,99),FIND("$",MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(E3&"1"),0,1)),2,99))-1) | =LEFT(MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(F3&"1"),0,1)),2,99),FIND("$",MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(F3&"1"),0,1)),2,99))-1) |
|  | value sheet | Sheet1 |  |  |  |  |
|  | value row | 2 |  |  |  |  |
|  | value column | AL | =LEFT(MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(C6&"1"),0,1)),2,99),FIND("$",MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(C6&"1"),0,1)),2,99))-1) | =LEFT(MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(D6&"1"),0,1)),2,99),FIND("$",MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(D6&"1"),0,1)),2,99))-1) | =LEFT(MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(E6&"1"),0,1)),2,99),FIND("$",MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(E6&"1"),0,1)),2,99))-1) | =LEFT(MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(F6&"1"),0,1)),2,99),FIND("$",MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(F6&"1"),0,1)),2,99))-1) |
|  | case sheet | Sheet1 |  |  |  |  |
|  | case row | 2 |  |  |  |  |
|  | case column | B |  |  |  |  |
|  | weight index address | Sheet1!$AK$729:$AK$734 |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | weight | ="INDIRECT(""" & $C$1 &"!" & C3 & """&ROW(" & $C$1 &"!" & $C$3 & "$" & $C$2 &")-1+MATCH(" & $C$7 &"!" & $C$9 & $C$8 &"," & $C$10 &",0))" | ="INDIRECT(""" & $C$1 &"!" & D3 & """&ROW(" & $C$1 &"!" & $C$3 & "$" & $C$2 &")-1+MATCH(" & $C$7 &"!" & $C$9 & $C$8 &"," & $C$10 &",0))" | ="INDIRECT(""" & $C$1 &"!" & E3 & """&ROW(" & $C$1 &"!" & $C$3 & "$" & $C$2 &")-1+MATCH(" & $C$7 &"!" & $C$9 & $C$8 &"," & $C$10 &",0))" | ="INDIRECT(""" & $C$1 &"!" & F3 & """&ROW(" & $C$1 &"!" & $C$3 & "$" & $C$2 &")-1+MATCH(" & $C$7 &"!" & $C$9 & $C$8 &"," & $C$10 &",0))" | ="INDIRECT(""" & $C$1 &"!" & G3 & """&ROW(" & $C$1 &"!" & $C$3 & "$" & $C$2 &")-1+MATCH(" & $C$7 &"!" & $C$9 & $C$8 &"," & $C$10 &",0))" |
|  | value | =$C$4&"!" &C6&$C$5 | =$C$4&"!" &D6&$C$5 | =$C$4&"!" &E6&$C$5 | =$C$4&"!" &F6&$C$5 | =$C$4&"!" &G6&$C$5 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| weight * AND(value<>0, value<>"N/A") | formula 1 | =C13&"*"&"AND("&C14&"<>0,"&C14&"<>""N/A"")" | =D13&"*"&"AND("&D14&"<>0,"&D14&"<>""N/A"")" | =E13&"*"&"AND("&E14&"<>0,"&E14&"<>""N/A"")" | =F13&"*"&"AND("&F14&"<>0,"&F14&"<>""N/A"")" | =G13&"*"&"AND("&G14&"<>0,"&G14&"<>""N/A"")" |
| previous formula for cell 1 + previous formula for cell 2 + previous formula for cell 3 + previous formula for cell 4 + previous formula for cell 5 | formula 2 | =C16&"+"&D16&"+"&E16&"+"&F16&"+"&G16 |  |  |  |  |
| value * weight / previous formula | formula 3 | =C14&"*"&C13&"/"&"("&$C17&")" | =D14&"*"&D13&"/"&"("&$C17&")" | =E14&"*"&E13&"/"&"("&$C17&")" | =F14&"*"&F13&"/"&"("&$C17&")" | =G14&"*"&G13&"/"&"("&$C17&")" |
| IF(OR(value = "N/A", value = 0), 0, previous formula) | formula 4 | ="IF(OR("&C14&"=""N/A"","&C14&"=0),0,"&C18&")" | ="IF(OR("&D14&"=""N/A"","&D14&"=0),0,"&D18&")" | ="IF(OR("&E14&"=""N/A"","&E14&"=0),0,"&E18&")" | ="IF(OR("&F14&"=""N/A"","&F14&"=0),0,"&F18&")" | ="IF(OR("&G14&"=""N/A"","&G14&"=0),0,"&G18&")" |
| previous formula for cell 1 + previous formula for cell 2 + previous formula for cell 3 + previous formula for cell 4 + previous formula for cell 5 | formula 5 | =C19&"+"&D19&"+"&E19&"+"&F19&"+"&G19 |  |  |  |  |

Crazy formulas calls for crazy way to edit.

Comment: Thanks Evil Blue Monkey it works.  I was hoping to handle it with VB, but the instructions were for Excel only.  It's certainly a brute force solution, but I wasn't sure how to do it in a more elegant manner in Excel.

Comment: What if I wanted to check another cell first (say B2) and based on that use the formula from Evil Blue Monkey to apply the formula?  So if B2 is "Dog" I will still run the whole formula but I'll reference Row 729 with the formulas in it and if B2 is "Cat" I will still run the formula but I'll reference Row 730.  I can handle the references form within the formula, but how to add the additional level of IF to start with (I will have six different animals).

Comment: @GreggRosenstein: well, i'd say that the sanest way would be to use a second cell to translate the dog/cat/... into address or offset values and then use an `INDIRECT` function to pick the right range. Then again: that formula isn't for sanest approach. Is these a complete list of animals and proper ranges? Is it a fixed list or is it supposely going to change in the relative near future? Is there a maximum number of animals? We will probably go with a `VLOOKUP` to pick the animal from the list.

Comment: I've edited the answer. I've assumed that the kind of animal will vary with each row, therefore i kept B2 as non-absolute. I've assumed that the list of the animals will be coherent with the animals specified, that their data will also be coherently ordered and that it will be placed in column B in the same rows of the animals' reference data. I've used the cell AD729 to "measure" the starting row of the data, so you will be able to move them without worrying about the formula.

Comment: I used animals as an example but they are actually types of vehicles.  The weights (and therefore calculations) change based on the type of vehicle in B2, C2, D2, etc.   Age Visual Measured Maintenance Reliability
Bus Fleet  35% 10% 10% 10% 35%
Commuter Rail Fleet  10% 35% 0% 20% 35%
Ferry Fleet  25% 25% 0% 25% 25%
Non-Revenue Fleet Rubber Tire Vehicles 80% 20% 0% 0% 0%
Non-Revenue Fleet Steel Wheel Vehicles 80% 20% 0% 0% 0%
Paratransit  30% 20% 30% 20% 0%
Transit Rail Car Fleet  40% 10% 0% 10% 40% so if it's Bus Fleet then we use the weights in the first line, etc.

Comment: @GreggRosenstein: ok. Is the new formula working?

Comment: I will implement it later today and let you know.  I'll leave a comment here for you one way or the other.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Evil Blue Monkey can I show you my screenshots elsewhere ?

Comment: The determining cell is in B2, B3, B4, etc.  That will tell me which row of weights to use (either AL729:AP729, AL730:AP730, AL731:AP731, etc.  The scores are in cells AL2:AP2, AL3:AP3, AL4:AP4, etc.  I can adapt the cell names from what you have provided.  I just want to make sure the match and indirect concepts are right.

Comment: Evil Blue Monkey my weighting cells based on category are like this:                           
Bus Fleet  35% 10% 10% 10% 35%
Ferry Flee  25% 25% 0% 25% 25%                                           
so column B has bus fleet, ferry fleet, etc. my scores are in AL2:AP2, and the weights I use (for bus) are in AL729:AP729.  I can put the term 'Bus Fleet' in AK729 for the match.  If B2 is ferry instead of bus then my scores are still in AL2:AP2 and the weights I use for ferry are in AL730:AP730 and I would have the term 'ferry fleet' in AK730.  How does that affect what you sent?  Thanks!

Comment: So each rows has 5 data instead of 6. I guess it will be easier to rewrite the formula step by step.

Comment: @GreggRosenstein: new formula posted. Try it.

Comment: Evil Blue Monkey it's throwing me a #NAME? error.  Maybe because we need a 6th iteration of the text?  We're referencing 729-734 because there are 6 different B2 options but the formula only runs 5 times?  I know there are 5 columns, but those are AL2-AP2 and accounted for within each iteraton.  I so appreciate your help with all of this!

Comment: Nah, it was probaly a `&` where there should have been a `$`. I've edited it. Try again.

Comment: Now I get an #N/A error.  When I evaluate I get IF(FALSE,#N/A,0.7/(INDIRECT("AL"&728+MATCH("Bus Fleet Bus Fleet",$AK$729:$AK$734,0)) with the MATCH and subsequent part underlined

Comment: Btw I'm assuming all instances of fleet are replaced by Bus Fleet in the first block and replaced by Commuter Rail Fleet in the second block.  There are six types of vehicles but only five blocks of code.

Comment: Ok, this really looks badly arranged. Straight question: what can i find in column B and what will be the correct match in the $AK$729:$AK$734 range?

Comment: Column B has six possible options - Bus Fleet, Commuter Rail Fleet, Ferry Fleet, Non-Revenue Fleet, Paratransit, or Transit Rail Car Fleet.  I have the weights based on the vehicle type in rows 729-734 with the vehicle type in AK and the weights in AL-AP llke such Bus Fleet 35% 10% 10% 10% 35%
Commuter Rail Fleet 10% 35% 0% 20% 35%
Ferry Fleet 25% 25% 0% 25% 25%
Non-Revenue Fleet 80% 20% 0% 0% 0%
Paratransit 30% 20% 30% 20% 0%
Transit Rail Car Fleet 40% 10% 0% 10% 40%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246258/discussion-between-evil-blue-monkey-and-gregg-rosenstein).